# Updating youtube privacyStatus getting madeForKidsModificationNotAllowed error

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm updating a live stream privacy setting using the youtube API with something like this:

```
gapi.client.youtube.liveBroadcasts.update({
      "part": [
        "id,status"
      ],
      "resource": {
        "id": "ID_OF_STREAM",
        "status": {
          "privacyStatus": "public"
        }
      }
    })
```

It returns an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The madeForKids field is read-only",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The madeForKids field is read-only",
        "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
        "reason": "madeForKidsModificationNotAllowed",
        "extendedHelp": "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#status.madeForKids"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why does youtube think I'm updating the madeForKids property? I just want to change the stream's privacy setting from "public" to "private" and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

if you check the documentation [LiveBroadcasts: update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/update) you will find the following

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts
```

This call is a [HTTP PUT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT) request not a [HTTP PATCH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH) request.

> The HTTP PUT request method creates a new resource or replaces a representation of the target resource with the request payload.

I suspect you're confusing it with a [HTTP PATCH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH) request

> The HTTP PATCH request method applies partial modifications to a resource.

With a HTTP PUT requests the API assumes that you are sending everything you would like updated. So any fields that you send as null will attempt to be updated to NULL and that field is read only so you cant update it.   So if there is a field you don't want updated you will need to send its current value back to the server or it's going to be updated to null.